# Materialize disappear when I will use codeigniter url

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I have a strange problem. Im usining Codeigniter with MaterializeCSS. I want to create navs to create menu. The problem is when I use localhost/page everything works fine, navbars are visible, but When I'll use a site.url, page looks like materalize is not included. I don't know what to do. I can quess there is something with URL in browser[image]

[image: localhost/page]
[image: after forwarding]
Controller:

```
class main extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->view('head');
        $this->load->view('index');
        }
        public function index()
        {
        $this->load->model('quiz_model');
        $data['result'] = $this->quiz_model->get_data();
        $this->load->view('content/quiz', $data);
        }
        public function addquestion()
        {
            $this->load->view('content/addquestion');
        }
}
```

index.php

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('html');
$this->load->helper('url');
?>
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <?php echo '<li><a href="' .site_url("main").'">web page</a></li>' ?>
            <?php echo '<li><a href="' .site_url("main/addquestion").'">Dodaj pytanie</a></li>' ?>      
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

head.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <title>Strona</title>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="container">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the base url you have IP showing in url.

config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectname/';
```

Comment: After that url on the browser looks correct, but materialize is still invisible for other pages

Answer (score 0):

You need to change few line :

*Controller* :

```
    ...
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('url');  // move url helper here, so it could be used on head view
    $this->load->view('head');
    $this->load->view('index');
    }
    ...
```

*head.php* :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url() ?>css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url() ?>js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <title>Strona</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
```